# Any recommendation for zip file upload by java servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I need to upload zip file to server by servlet? anyone can recommend me one? which can upload the zip file and then unzip the zip file. it will be good if it support upload several files together. thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload files in JSP/Servlet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824)

Answer (score 0):

use [apache commons fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/)

see [this](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html) example